# Building a Matrix of uneven number of rows with Panda

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if the title is not really informative, having hard time to formulate it.

I have some data, upon massaging with size(), sorted on count, I am getting a count of tactic, technique as below:

```py
tactic            technique      
Defense Evasion   A                2
                  B                2
                  C                1
Machine Learning  D               496
                  E                1
```

I would like to transform it to 2 dataframe, one with the tactics:

```py
Defense Evasion    Machine Learning
A                         D
B                         E
C
```

And the other with the counts, where i will apply some sort of heatmaps coloring:

```py
Defense Evasion    Machine Learning
2                         496
2                          1
1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get first index levels value with `.index.get_level_values(0)`. Then loop through the unique values to get next level values and column values.

```py
d1 = {}
d2 = {}

for index in s.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    d1[index] = s.loc[index].index.tolist()
    d2[index] = s.loc[index].reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index').T
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

```
print(df1)
  Defense Evasion Machine Learning
0               A                D
1               B                E
2               C             None

print(df2)
   Defense Evasion  Machine Learning
0                2             496.0
1                2               1.0
2                1               NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop()` ,`reset_index()`, `pivot()`, `apply()`, `sorted()` and `dropna()` method for your 1st dataframe:

```
df1=df.drop(columns=['technique']).reset_index().pivot(columns='level_0',values='tactic').apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna(subset=['Defense Evasion'])
```

Finally:

```
df1.columns.name=''
```

Now if you print `df1` you will get:

```
    Defense Evasion     Machine Learning
0   A                   D
1   B                   E
2   C                   NaN
```

Now For your second dataframe you can use `droplevel()`, `reset_index()`, `pivot()` ,`apply()`, `sorted()` and `dropna()` method:

```
df2=df.droplevel(1).reset_index().pivot(columns='index',values='technique').apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna(subset=['Defense Evasion'])
```

Finally:

```
df2.columns.name=''
```

Now If you print `df2` you will get:

```
    Defense Evasion     Machine Learning
0   2.0                 496.0
1   2.0                 1.0
2   1.0                 NaN
```